# New line (/n) not working in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to make a power calculator program in Python 2.7. It worked but I tried to write the values into a file and the /n didn't work. Here is the program:

```
import math
file =  open("numbers.txt" , 'w')
c = 0
a = int(raw_input("A number:  "))
b = int(raw_input("To the power   "))
h = range(b)
h.append(b)
print 1
file.write('1')
for c in range(b):
    print int((math.pow(a, h[c+1])))
    k = (int((math.pow(a, h[c+1]))))
    file.write((str(k)+"/n") `
```

Comment: It's `\n`. Not `/n`

Comment: I've flagged this as off-topic on the grounds that your problem is caused by a simple typographical error. You wanted to write `\n`.

Comment: Also note that *"not working"* isn't a very helpful problem description; give a [mcve].

Comment: I don't really think it's off-topic. Sure, the question isn't a good one. But it's still an issue with his code and he needs help with solving it.

Comment: @NullDev Sure. We normally answer simple typo question in a comment, since they are usually almost impossible to search for and hence of little use to future readers, and so the system will automatically delete them after a few days unless they have a positive-score answer. This one's title _does_ make it useful; OTOH, if you try to search for this question using Google you'll never find it: searches like `new line (/n) Python` just bring up hits for `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a normal slash (`/`). But you need to use a Backslash (`\`).
So, `\n` will add a new line.
`\` is used for escape sequence.